# Чат Бот Битрикс 24 - RabbitMQ - Телеграм бот

Tags: php, бот, битрикс24, rabbitmq

В общем, бьюсь уже над задачей не 1 неделю.

Что имеем

- Телеграмм бот на Питоне
- Реббит
- Чат бота битрикса (чистый php)

Вопрос в следующем, имеется ли возможность чтобы данный бот (В Битриксе) передавал сообщение пользователя в канал Реббита, его получал ТГ И отправлял обратно через канал в Битру.

Реализовывал ли кто похожее?

Вопрос в следующем: К примеру убираем чат бота битрикса, возможно ли как то из битрикса общаться на прямую с тг ботом (Обычному пользователю)

Comment: Вроде через открытые линий можно что то подобное релизовать